# VBA - Remove Duplicates Across Multiple Sheets in Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheets in a particular workbook, and n each sheet there are Employee Numbers. The sheets have already been sorted in a way that Column A is always the Employee Number.

So what I need to do is loop through all the sheets and apply the RemoveDuplicates function to delete all duplicate Employee Numbers found in Column A.

Note - I am not trying to have the Employee Number appear on only one sheet; I am trying to have the Employee Number appear only once on each sheet.

I have it working for when I name a specific sheet, but cannot get it to work in a loop.

*Test1:*

```
Sub deleteDuplicate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wkbk1 As Workbook
    Dim w As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long

    Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    wkbk1.Activate

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' Find last row in column A
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1

            ws.lRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

        Next iCntr

    Next ws

End Sub
```

*Test2:*

```
Sub deleteDuplicate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wkbk1 As Workbook
    Dim w As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long

    Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    wkbk1.Activate

    With wkbk1

        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.count

            With Worksheets(w)

                .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

            End With

        Next w

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In test 1, you're not using `iCntr` in your loop. However, test 2 works just fine for me.

Comment: @dwirony I get an error with Test 2 - Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: What is the name of your workbook, and what do you have in the macro on line `Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")`?

Comment: I was vainly trying to make your code work, and after a (big) while I found that my version of excel (2003) does not support RemoveDuplicates functionality. Which version of Excel are you running?

Comment: @dwirony I have that exact line of code. The debug gets stuck on the line .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes with the error I mentioned above.

Comment: @CMArg I am using Excel 2013.. It should be working in this version.

Comment: @EitelDagnin Hm, how is your data set up? I wonder if it's an issue with the `UsedRange` - maybe try changing that to an actual range (like `Range("A1:G1000")`)

Comment: @dwirony Okay, I made a specific range Range("A:M") and it works just fine.. But it would be much better if I could have a dynamic range instead

Comment: @EitelDagnin Dynamic for rows, columns, or both? You can find the lastrow/lastcol value and make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in both tests

- `Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")` - it implies the code is not in `ThisWorkbook`, yet

  - **`Test 1`** uses `ThisWorkbook` - explicitly (`For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`)
  - **`Test 2`** uses `ThisWorkbook` - implicitly (`With Worksheets(w)`)
- For this to work the file `"3rd Party.xlsm"` must be open at the same time

Try the versions bellow, and if the code is not running in `ThisWorkbook`, update `wb` accordingly

(`ThisWorkbook` is the file where the VBA code is executed from)

---

.

**`Version 1`** - determine last row and last column

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteDuplicates1()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long, ur As Range

    On Error Resume Next    'Expected error: wb not found
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Set ur = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lr, lc))
            ur.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

.

**`Version 2`** - UsedRange

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicates2()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next    'Expected error: wb not found
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If nothing happens when you run either of these versions, the file `"3rd Party.xlsm"` doesn't exist.
Either it's not open currently, or the name is different - maybe `"3rd Party.xlsx"` (with an `x`)

.

If you still have errors for Version 2, `.UsedRange` may not be what you expect

Try cleaning extra rows and columns with this Sub

---

```
Public Sub RemoveEmptyRowsAndColumns()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long, er As Range, ec As Range

    On Error Resume Next    'Expected error: wb not found
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'Workbooks("3rd Party.xlsm")

    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

            lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If lr > 1 And lc > 1 Then

                Set er = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lr + 1, "A"), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A"))
                Set ec = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc + 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count))

                er.EntireRow.Delete     'Shift:=xlUp
                ec.EntireColumn.Delete  'Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Paul Bica. It works great and I really appreciate the effort you put into your reply. :)

Comment: Glad it helped!